# javascript_include_tag "directory/file" results in incorrect path for //= require assets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, asset-pipeline, sprockets

I want to use `//= require <lib>` from a different file than `/app/assets/javascripts/application.js`. This results in a asset compile error but the problem is that the path is incorrect. I made a simplified project that show the problem available at https://github.com/rusanu/test-ember.

In the [layout](https://github.com/rusanu/test-ember/blob/master/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb):

```
<head>
  <title>TestEmber</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
  <%= yield :head %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
```

In the [view](https://github.com/rusanu/test-ember/blob/master/app/views/dashboard/show.html.erb):

```
<%= content_for :head do %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "dashboard/dashboard", :cache => 'dashboard' %>
<% end %>
```

and in my [dashboard/dashboard.js](https://github.com/rusanu/test-ember/blob/master/app/assets/javascripts/dashboard/dashboard.js):

```
//= require handlebars
//= require ember
//= require ember-data
//= require_self
```

This results in error:

```
Showing /home/rremus/test-ember/app/views/dashboard/show.html.erb where line #2 raised:

No such file or directory - Asset file not found at '/home/rremus/test-ember/public/home/rremus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/handlebars-source-1.0.0.rc4/dist/handlebars.js'
Extracted source (around line #2):

1: <%= content_for :head do %>
2: <%= javascript_include_tag "dashboard", :cache => 'dashboard' %>
3: <% end %>
4: 
5: <h1>Dashboard#show</h1>
```

Notice how the asset path consist of the project public directory (`/home/rremus/test-ember/public`) and then correct asset path (`/home/rremus/.rvm/...`) is appended, resulting into an incorrect path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that you have to do some special gymnastics to get it working with the cache directive in this case based on the [Rails guide for the asset pipeline](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#main-features).

If you ditch the cache directive and rely on precompilation to handle file combination then things seem to work without error.

Comment: Indeed, removing the cache directive fixes the problems.